# Force iOS to download image from HTML5 Canvas (using pure javascript)

Tags: javascript, ios, html, html5-canvas, base64

This question has been asked before and the general response is that it can't be done on iOS. **However** those questions are several years old, and it is possible that a workaround has been developed, or that there is now a way to do this.

I have a working pure JavaScript image editor that will not let the final editing step, saving the edited image, happen in iOS. It's hard to believe that this is **impossible**. So, a simple question: is there a way to download the canvas image to an iOS user's mobile device?

EDIT: I have tried integrating the first answer below into my code, but I obviously have the syntax wrong. Here is the pre-existing code with the new code in "if(isIOS())..." block. The code is taking me to a new page with the url "domain name/iString" and generating a 404 since iString obviously does not exist as a document.

```
// Save a JPG (with quality setting) or full quality PNG to user's drive. 

function fileSave()
{

  var canvas = document.getElementById('cSave');

  if (document.getElementById("png").checked == true)
  {
    var quality = null;     
    var format = "image/png"; 
    var name = "new_image.png"; 
  }

  if (document.getElementById("jpg").checked == true)
  {
    var format = "image/jpeg";  
    var quality = Number(document.getElementById("quality").value) / 100; 
    var name = "new_image.jpg"
  }

  canvas.toBlob(function(blob) // Send canvas to blob and download blob 
  {
    const anchor = document.createElement('a')
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
    anchor.href = url
    anchor.download = name, 
    document.body.appendChild(anchor)

    // begin new code block 
    if (isIOS()) 
    {
    var iString = btoa(blob); 
    // data:[<mediatype>][;base64],<data>
    iString = "data: " + format + ";base64," + iString; 
    document.getElementById("iOS").innerHTML = '<a href="iString">click me</a>';   
    }
    // end new code block 

    anchor.click()
    document.body.removeChild(anchor)
    URL.revokeObjectURL(url);   
    }, format, quality)
}
```

EDIT: I got it to work in Firefox (Windows 7). As somewhat expected, it does not work in Chrome ("Not allowed to navigate top frame to data URL") error.

```
if (!isIOS()) // note the ! for desktop testing 
{
var iString = canvas.toDataURL(); 
document.getElementById("iOS").innerHTML = '<a href="' + iString + '">click me</a>';   
}
```

But, when I remove the "!", expecting it to work in iOS, it does not work on any browser (including Firefox). The iPhone app "Inspect" returns a "canvas.toBlob() is not a function" error, which might be expected in Safari ("Inspect" may be using Safari), but I apparently still do not have the syntax right for other browsers in iOS.

LAST EDIT FOR TONIGHT:

This opens a new window in iOS Firefox, but there's no image, just a small (maybe 6 pixel x 6 pixel) empty box.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('cSave');
var convert = btoa(canvas); 
convert = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + convert;   
document.getElementById("iOS").innerHTML = '<a href="' + convert + '" target="_blank">click me</a>';
```

Also, the base64 string does not appear long enough.

```
data:image/jpeg%3Bbase64,W29iamVjdCBIVE1MQ2FudmFzRWxlbWVudF0=
```

On https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter this appears as a box with a small broken image icon.

Thank you

PS: Still having issues but **"From there they could use one of the two system dialogs to save the image."** I don't see any available system dialogs on my iPhone using iOS 10.2.1.

Answer (score 2):

While it is impossible to save am image directly to the camera roll from a web app, most users are familiar with saving images on their own.

When the user wishes to save their image, you could create a [data uri](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) and have them open it in a new tab. From there they could use one of the two system dialogs to save the image.

Comment: I'm pleased to know that it's possible! **Please see my edit, above. Thank you very much!**  

I'll be AFK for a bit for a conference call.

Comment: [HTMLCanvasElement.toDataURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL) this should make your life easier :)

Comment: Yes, it did, thank you very much.  I'm pulling in an image of the wrong canvas for some strange reason, but I'm sure I can fix that.  The remaining issue is **"From there they could use one of the two system dialogs to save the image."** On my iPhone, I don't see any system dialog in the new tab that could save the image. What am I missing?

Comment: This is apparently one of the ways: _"To save an image sent to you in Mail or Safari, it's as easy as tapping and holding on the image in question. When the share sheet pops up, just tap the Save Image button to send the photo to your Camera Roll."_ from https://www.imore.com/save-any-picture-web-your-iphone-or-ipad

Comment: So much for that idea. I'm not mixing up the canvases. _Even though clicking the save button saves the image with the cssFilter applied, iOS is opening the new tab with the original image (cssFilter not applied)._