# Force iOS to download image from HTML5 Canvas (using pure javascript) AND keep CSS filters applied

Tags: javascript, ios, html, css, css-filters

Reference is made to this post, which partially answered my question: [Force iOS to download image from HTML5 Canvas (using pure JavaScript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50262986/force-ios-to-download-image-from-html5-canvas-using-pure-javascript)

In summary, that question has been asked before and the general response is that it can't be done on iOS. However, those questions are several years old, 
and the member who replied to the above question did supply a partial answer:   using HTMLCanvasElement.toDataURL() to convert the image to a data URL, and then forcing the data URL to open as an image in a new tab.  From there, it could then be downloaded by holding a finger on the image, opening the iOS save dialog box.

The problem is, even though my save code downloads the image with the CSS Filters applied, the image that opens in a new tab on iOS does **not** have the filters applied.

So, my question is, how do I take the final step: forcing the image that opens in the new tab to have the CSS Filters applied, just as a downloaded image on a computer would have the CSS Filters applied.

This is the code that takes the image from the original canvas and applies the CSS Filters, creating a new image with the CSS Filters applied:

```
function fileApply() 
{ 

  var cP = document.getElementById("cPreview");
  var cntxCP = cP.getContext("2d");

  var cS = document.getElementById("cSave");
  var cntxCS = cS.getContext("2d");

  // take whatever CSS filters are applied to the first canvas
  var cssFilter = getComputedStyle(cP).filter; 

  // use those filter as the second canvas' context's filter
  cS.width = cP.width; 
  cS.height = cP.height; 
  cntxCS.filter = cssFilter;

  cntxCS.drawImage(cP, 0, 0);
  cP.style.display = "none";   
  if (cS.style.display == "none") cS.style.display = "block";   
}
```

That all works.

This is the save code:

```
function fileSave()
{

  var canvas = document.getElementById('cSave');

  if (document.getElementById("png").checked == true)
  {
    var quality = null;  // canvas.toBlob() takes an extra argument if file type is JPG. Set quality to null to allow PNG downloads. Quality value will be supplied if JPG is selected.   
    var format = "image/png"; 
    var name = "new_image.png"; 
  }

  if (document.getElementById("jpg").checked == true)
  {
    var format = "image/jpeg";  
    var quality = Number(document.getElementById("quality").value) / 100; 
    var name = "new_image.jpg"
  }

  if (!isIOS())
  {
    canvas.toBlob(function(blob) // Send canvas to blob and download blob 
    {
    const anchor = document.createElement('a')
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
    anchor.href = url
    anchor.download = name, 
    document.body.appendChild(anchor)
    anchor.click()
    document.body.removeChild(anchor)
    URL.revokeObjectURL(url);   
    }, format, quality)
  }

  if (isIOS()) 
  {
    var iString = canvas.toDataURL(); // convert image to base64 string 
    document.getElementById("iOS").innerHTML = '<a href="' + iString + '">click me</a>'; // add string to url and target new tab.     
  }
```

That works fine on a computer.  On iOS that creates the new image in a new tab **without** the CSS Filters applied.

Thank you

Comment: It downloads with the filters on it? Does that mean `iString` has the filters applied? CSS just affects the way the page renders, not the canvas data. Sounds like you need canvas filters.

Comment: _Yes, it downloads with the filters applied_. Thus, since iString is getting the image from the same place, it should have the filters applied. But it doesn't.  

CSS can be made to do more than just change how the page renders, in this case, it changes the actual image that's downloaded. 

I'm not sure what you mean by "canvas filters", is that something from a JS add-on library?

Comment: I just tested the above code on a custom filter I built (in other words, my own image filter, not a CSS3 filter). On iOS, the edited image opened in a new tab, with the filter's changes applied, and I was able to save it to the camera roll.  So, that confirms that everything else works, the sole issue is keeping the CSS3 filters applied when using CSS3 filters.

Comment: @PHPglue In regard to using "canvas filters", I read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/filter.  It appears to me that what I'm doing above, specifically
    
`var cssFilter = getComputedStyle(cP).filter;`  
`cntxCS.filter = cssFilter;` 
`cntxCS.drawImage(cP, 0, 0);`

**is** using canvas filters.  Did you have something else in mind? If so, please provide source code, because I don't see how what I'm doing differs from canvas filters. Thank you very much!

Comment: `getComputedStyle(cP).filter`? Pretty sure that won't work on any Browser. `canvasContext.filter` will work on Firefox, but not with most Browsers anyways. Use another technique.

Comment: @PHPglue Both techniques work in Firefox and Chrome (non-iOS). Neither work on Firefox or Chrome on iOS.

Comment: @PHPglue "Use another technique" Uh... when it comes to iOS, I would be happy to! Do you know of another technique?

Comment: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/imagefilters/ & http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php